# inserted data are not showing in the table of phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql

my php code:

```
$id=$_POST['id']; 
$name=$_POST['name'];
$phone=$_POST['phone'];
$mug=$_POST['mug']; 
$mug_name=$_POST['mug_name'];
$mug_color=$_POST['mug_color'];

function getData($db) 
{
    $stmt=$db->query("insert into data 
                    values('$id','$name','$phone','$mug','$mug_name','$mug_color');");
    return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
try {
   getData($db);} 
catch(PDOException $ex) {
   //handle me
}
```

my database table is only displaying id. other field is remaining empty?

Comment: You can't `fetch` an `insert`. The `id` column isn't auto incrementing? You are open to SQL injections, and it would be better to define the columns you are inserting into.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I define id as auto increment. my database is only showing id value other fields are empty

Comment: `$id` is not being passed either. Define the columns in the `insert` query and leave the `id` out.

Comment: This is a scope issue.  Your variables aren't defined within the scope of the `getData()` function. That being said, you _really_ should be using prepared statements with bound parameters, as showing in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it like this:

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=example', 'username', 'password');

$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO tabelle (column1, column2, column3) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");
$statement->execute(array($var1, $var2,$var3));
```

Replace host, dbname, username, and password. Then Replace the column1, column2,column3... with the actual column name and add a ? for each row you add. Var1 belongs to row 1 and so on...

Comment: FYI, you're confusing "rows" and "columns".

Comment: This method is also preventing SQL injections

Comment: I edited the code but its still not working. Its not showing any error but its not displaying the values in the database table either.

Comment: did you replace tabelle with your table name?

Comment: function getData($db) {
   $stmt = $db->prepare("insert into data ( id,name,phone,mug,mug_name,mug_color) values(?,?,?,?,?,?);");
   $stmt->execute(array($var1, $var2,$var3, $var4, $var5, $var6));  
   return $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
 

try {
   getData($db);
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
   //handle me.
}  my edited code

Comment: i suppose that you have to pass the variables to the function